# active_domain not found in context when using wizard

Tags: odoo-9

I'm trying to get the `active_domain` to a wizard.When I use :

```
self.env.context.get('active_domain',False)
```

This works only when I check "select all check box" but when I select a few items and execute the wizard, I cannot find the active_domain in context, is this a bug or I'm doing it wrong?

**P.S: I'm using Odoo 9**

Comment: Can you use `active_ids` instead or do you need the domain for some reason?

Comment: I need active_domain because it contains information about the current domain in the tree view